# Not Able to add groovy files to source folders

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have a project with groovy files in src/main/groovy and these files are used in src/main/java and I am getting error for groovy file references. I am not able to see my groovy files in the class path.
My pom.xml has the code to set groovy source folders

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/groovy</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1-01</version>
            <!-- <extensions>true</extensions> -->
        </plugin>
        <!-- Plugin Management -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <!-- Source includes is necessary to allow groovy files in the java 
                    folder, else eclipse will throw a filtering exception -->
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
                <!-- Download sources will make maven download and attach source files 
                    where available -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerVersion>${java-version}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>add-test-source</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

please suggest any changes to be done to get groovy files source folders into class path

Comment: Do u have a mix of groovy and java classes or groovy only ?

Comment: If you have circular dependencies, then the easy way out is usually to just move all java files over to the groovy source root, since the groovy compiler just delegates to the regular java compiler for .java files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to your Eclipse project: Do the Groovy source folders appear before (aka above) the Java one's that depend on them in the Package Explorer?

For example, you may see something like this:

```
Package Explorer
  ProjectName
    src/main/java
    src/test/java
    src/main/groovy
    src/test/groovy
    Maven Dependencies
    JRE System Library
    ...
    pom.xml
```

The guide for using the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` adapter is here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin  There is a section for setting up the extra source folders.

Also, you can mix Groovy and Java sources in the src/*/groovy folders.  The groovy compiler adapter will jointly invoke the java compiler where necessary.